# How to resolve "Circular reference detected for service" issue?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to inject my repository service into EventListener but that leads me to following exception, which, with my basic knowledge of Symfony2, I have no idea how to resolve. Exception is:

> ServiceCircularReferenceException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2129:
>
> Circular reference detected for service  "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> person.connect.listener -> tag.repository.service".

And here is how I've declared repository and listener:

```
tag.repository.service:
    class: Application\Bundle\PersonBundle\Entity\TagRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
    arguments: [ Application\Bundle\PersonBundle\Entity\Tag ]

person.connect.listener:
    class: Application\Bundle\PersonBundle\EventListener\ConnectListener
    arguments:
        tokenStorage: "@security.token_storage"
        tagRepo: "@tag.repository.service"
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist, connection: default }
```

Most answers, that I've able to find, suggest injecting service container, but I really don't want do that. Is there any way to resolve this properly?

UPD: Here is the code of the listener. Everything worked fine until I've tried to inject TagRepository

```
class ConnectListener
{
/**
 * @var TokenStorage
 */
private $tokenStorage;

/**
 * @var TagRepository
 */
private $tagRepo;

/**
 * @param TokenStorage $tokenStorage
 * @param TagRepository $tagRepo
 */
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, TagRepository $tagRepo)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
/**
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
 * @return void
 */
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

    if ($entity instanceof Person) {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $visibility = new PersonVisibility($entity, $user);
        $visibility->setVisibilityType(PersonVisibility::VT_CREATED);
        $entityManager->persist($visibility);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of your eventlistener too?

Comment: @KhorneHoly - won't be able to do so for another 8 hours, until I get back home. But at this moment there is nothing related to tagRepo, and before I've added tagRepo everything were fine - on postPersist I'm retrieving current user ID from tokenStorage and using it to create record in table that connect Person and Users tables - nothing related to Tag and TagRepository.

Comment: @KhorneHoly - done, here is the listener

Comment: Uh, as far as I see, you don't even use `$tagRepo`? Or will this change?

Comment: @lxg - well, of course that will change) at least if I figure out how to deal with exception

Comment: @SergeyNester what Symfony2 version are you running?

Comment: @SergeyNester: What happens if you omit the `connection: default` parameter in the tag?

Comment: @KhorneHoly 2.7.something, I believe

Comment: @lxg: actually - exactly nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as TagRepository is descendant of EntityRepository try obtaining its instance in postPersist event. Like this:

```
// using full classname:
$tagRepo = $entityManager->getRepository("Application\Bundle\PersonBundle\Entity\TagRepository");
// alternatively:
$tagRepo = $entityManager->getRepository("ApplicationPersonBundle:Tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can also change your declaration of your repository, don't use the factory and use [one of these 2 methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54939370/2134945).

This will avoid the circular reference and will be cleaner than use the EntityManager class.